Several programs have been dropped from the Launcher and the Superkey malfunctions. How do I easily restore them? 20.04LTS
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04LTS. For some unknown reason, several programs have been dropped from the Launcher. Also, the superkey brings up the "Search Your Computer" screen, but it no longer works.
Luckily, programs can still be accessed via Nautilus by right-clicking on an arbitrary file, selecting "Open With Other Application", then selecting "View All Applications". From this list of installed programs you can select and execute the one you desire.
Fortunately, when you launch a program, Nautilus places its icon on the Launcher. Right-click and there is the option to declare the program "Favorite", thus putting it back on the Launcher.
If anyone knows a simple way to fix the superkey problem, it would be appreciated.  Thank you.
